# Is any way in solr3 slave create update delete will reflect on master also

Tags: solr

Is any way in solr3,
To perform create update delete on slave will also reflect on master?

Answer (score 0):

No. Slave is merely a slave and can't control master. If the slave was able to edit/delete records in master then the whole purpose of master/slave is defeated.

Ideally, there shouldn't be any data import handler (DIH) configured for slave, and it should ONLY be a master to create, update & delete documents. Slave just replicates what master has indexed. End of story!

Shishir